# Audit belongsTo relationship in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationships, audit

I have a model 'Contract' and a model 'ContractLine' in a classic master-detail relationship. In Laravel terms: the contractlines have a belongsTo relationship with a contract. I would like to audit all changes a user makes to his contracts. Not just the changes in the general 'contracts' table but also changes/additions/deletes in the underlying 'contract_lines'.

I have looked at [laravel-auditing](https://github.com/owen-it/laravel-auditing) by owen-it, and [cs-revisionable](https://github.com/csinghdev/cs-revisionable) by csinghdev but I'm not sure if they support this kind of auditing.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using [laravel-auditing](http://laravel-auditing.com/), tagging my ContractLine with the Contract's id (using generateTags) and adding a method 'getAllAudits' to my Contract model. This method concatenates the Contract audits and its underlying ContractLine audits. In my audits presentation I check the 'auditable_type' field of each audit to make a distinction between audits on the contracts and audits on the contractlines.

Still it feels a little hacky, a native solution would be better.

Comment: Hi, it'll be much helpful if you put the sample model codes of Contract and ContractLine in the answer.

Comment: hey, can you give some example code sample. Thank you

Comment: Based on Kirk's example, here's the trait I wrote to help pull related models:


   ```
<?php

    namespace App\Traits;

    use App\Models\Audit;

    trait GetsRelatedAudits
    {
        public function getAllAudits() {
            return Audit::where('tags', $this->id)
                        ->orWhere('auditable_id', $this->id)
                        ->orderByDesc('created_at')
                        ->limit(20)
                        ->get();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can speak for [Laravel Auditing](http://www.laravel-auditing.com).

It is indeed possible to audit multiple tables (i.e. Eloquent models).

To achieve that, you will have to implement the `Auditable` interface in the `Contract` and the `ContractLine` models.

Basically, something like:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Auditable;

class Contract extends Model implements Auditable
{
    use \OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;

    // ...
}
```

Apply the same for the `ContractLine` model.

Take a look at the main sections of the [documentation](http://www.laravel-auditing.com/docs/6.0/installation), which has everything explained, including common issues when using the package.

Comment: Thanks. As you can see in my own answer I did just that, but added a getAllAudits method to my Contract model to retrieve both the audits on my Contract as well as the audits on its underlying ContractLines in one big collection.

Comment: Yeah, by the time I finished writing my answer, I saw you answered yourself. I don't quite understand how exactly the use of tags solved your issue, though. I feel I might have misunderstood your original problem, then.

Comment: I have the same issue. given the example above, if I wanted to do $contract->revisionTo($last_revision) and all of its relationships, would the example above work, or would I need to do this manually ?

Comment: @QuetzyGarcia This answer is expired